# PHP caching script - saving cached data not decreasing site page load

Tags: php, xml, caching

I am working on a site that is built on LAMP, which pulls data(car dealership inventories) from an XML feed and displays it on the site. There is a rotator on the index page which displays 4 random cars, however there is a long delay on page load - about 7-10 seconds. This is because the site is cycling through the data to find cars that have images and meet other criteria before displaying the results. My developer put together this script to cache the results for 5 minutes:

```
/* 
 * Cache requests for 5 minutes
 * Wraps original method (now _sendRequest)
 */
private function sendRequest($xml) {
    error_log($xml);
    $cache_filename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/' . md5($xml);
    if (file_exists($cache_filename) && (time() - filemtime($cache_filename)) < 300 && filesize($cache_filename) > 100) {
        return file_get_contents($cache_filename);
    } elseif (file_exists($cache_filename)) {
        unlink($cache_filename);
    }
    $response = $this->_sendRequest($xml);
    if (!is_dir(dirname($cache_filename))) {
       @mkdir(dirname($cache_filename),0775,true);
    }
    @file_put_contents($cache_filename, $response);
    return $response;
}

private function _sendRequest($xml) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120,
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => Config::$appName,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD         => Config::$aweAPIKey,
        CURLOPT_URL             => Config::$aweAPIURL,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $xml
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    //echo "ERROR: " . curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

The directory of the script is in /lib/client.php and it is saving large amounts of text files containing vehicle data in /lib/cache, however the site page load is not decreasing. Are there some changes I should make to the script or how it is saving the cached data?

Comment: your bottle neck is probably not in the request, but in the request processing. Is _sendRequest retrieving the xml or processing the xml?

Comment: also, it looks like your only caching for 300 seconds ... that's not very long

Comment: First of all, that cache would only be valid for 300 seconds if I am reading that correctly (the value 300 at the end represents seconds of time). Is that the desired length for the cache to persist? Are your requests faster within that 300s window.  Also what sort of value is passed to the function for $xml?

Also this shows nothing about the logic to filter through the XML data.  Your problem might be there.

Comment: Looked through client.php file and realized that the script is actually wrapping around the original sendRequest function - I added the full script in the original post. Does that help at all? Also, this same script was implemented in another site -www.dfwcertautos.com (which has the same core .php files), and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting the hard disk with every request is expensive in terms of performance, so logically your cache system there isn't really gonna help. Instead look into [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) as they allow you to store data directly in memory, which is much faster to read and write.